# boost python version

Tags: python, boost

I'm trying to use boost.python library in a C++ project (Windows + VS9) but it always tries to link against pyton25.lib.

Is it possible to link with version 2.6.x of python?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile boost-python library pointing Boost.Build to needed python version.
P.S. This heals a problem of undefined references while linking with library needed. I beleive you've already turned of autolinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting `-lpython26` when linking