# Looking for best way to Incorporate C++ dll with Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, dll, boost-python

I have a Python GUI application that needs to incorporate a somewhat complex C++ dll. I have looked into boost.python but was having difficulties as the program contains 5 separate C++ files and I have no prior C++ coding experience. I was able to get a test 'Hello World' C++ dll working with Python but that C++ code is simple compared to the dll I need.

I have gotten the dll to work with a Visual Basic project but am looking for the best possible solution for the same application in Python.

Would it be best to attempt to completely rewrite the C++ code in Python or try to get the boost.python wrappers coded correctly? If the time required to rewrite the code in python is comparable to the time it would take to code the wrappers would it be preferred to rewrite the code completely?

Would converting the dll code from a compiled language to an interpreted one show more negative affects than positive?

Thank you in advance,

Garrett

Answer (score 0):

I started using boost.python about a year ago as a novice/mid level C++ programmer, and I am very happy with my decision to go forward with it. The learning curve is steep, but it gradually eases up once you learn how to navigate the online documentation. I have trouble every now and then, but the best assistance I found on how to properly use boost.python as from previously asked questions on SO and independent blogs. There is a ton of online documentation out in the aether.

> Would it be best to attempt to completely rewrite the C++ code in Python or try to get the boost.python wrappers coded correctly?

This depends on:

1) How much 'heavy lifting' the C++ DLL is doing.

2) What type of arguments are being passed from Python into the C++ DLL.

3) How soon you need to deliver a working version of the code.

If you are creating instances of C++ objects, calling its members from python, and returning numpy arrays, this is relatively straightforward to do. If you need to operate on PyObjects in C++, then it can get a little tricky real fast. If you need to do the latter, be prepared to invest a bit more time and effort.

Also, keep in mind when you create the dll, the binary will be compatible with micro versions within the same major versions. I ran into portability issues in the past trying to run an *.so on a machine with Python2.7 installed on it, when it was linked against Python 2.6 libraries. See:

[Boost Python portability concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252598/boost-python-portability-concerns)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I suppose I will delve deeper into it and see how things go.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the easiest way is ctypes:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

This works as long as you can express your interface with a few C functions.
For most C++ libraries this is easy, as long as you don't need to subclass classes in order to use it.

Advantages:

- You compile you DLL without any special considerations for python (so you don't have the versioning problem mentioned in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18606365/1413374)
- You don't depend on a third party framework like boost or swig.
- Having a C interface for your DLL is a good thing anyway, for ABI stability reasons. (Adding class members changes the ABI of C++ classes, even if they are private)

> How would I go about doing this? Ctypes was the first thing I looked
>   into but I got the impression from various places that it would not
>   function properly with a C++ dll.

You declare your functions `extern "C"`. This s the easy part, you'll find details in any good C++ book.
The difficult part is to design the interface in a way that it doesn't need C++ features, like templates or inheritance.
"Abstract Datatypes" (ADT) is a nice design principle for this kind of things. Look it up.
For more detailed help, it would help if you could post the interface of your C++ library, or a part of it, so we can explain with an example.

Another issue is the C++ runtime. That must somehow be linked to your DLL. If you had linux, I'd suggest using libtool. I don't know about Windows. Maybe it just works. If it doesn't, put the error message into your favorite search machine.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Ctypes was the first thing I looked into but I got the impression from various places that it would not function properly with a C++ dll.

Comment: Yes, I agree ctype's is great because it doesn't rely on third party libraries. But the learning curve is significantly steeper than boost. Some things to keep in mind: you cannot access C++ members directly (you have to write a C wrapper for each one), memory management is a little more tricky, and it obfuscates the Python syntax. IMO, ctypes is a great for small projects.

Comment: That's what I wrote - it works as long as you can express your interface in C, easily. The learning curve was not too bad. Simpler than SWIG. I don't know about boost.python, never used it.